# Have the chapter title stick out of the type area

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, indentation, titlesec

I'm trying to place my chapter titles to the edge of the page, with a colored background box surrounding them. The surrounding boxes would need to be set outside of the body of the document. So far I have read the documentation of typearea, geometry, layouts, titlesec, TikZ and others but haven't been able to find a solution.

See http://latex-project.org/guides/lb2-ch4.pdf for an example of the effect I want to achieve. There the chapter title reaches farther right than the text body. 
What I want is to have my chapter titles in a a colored box similar to the headings on the 2nd page of the attached document on the left edge on the page.

Here is the code for the box. I just need a way to place it on the left page edge.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[uppercase, sf, explicit, raggedright]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[fill=cyan]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \color{white}   
    \draw (0,0) +(3ex,0) node[anchor=west]{Chapter \thechapter{} \filright#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chaptertitle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: With your current settings, long title will protrude into the right margin. A solution would be to declare an appropriate value for `text width` for the node. Also, unnumbered chapters produced with `\chapter*` will have an spurious chapter number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply set the 4th argument of `\titleformat` to a negative value.

In the following MWE I've set it at the left margin of the page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage[uppercase, sf, explicit, raggedright]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{}
{\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\hoffset-1in}
{%
    \tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[fill=cyan]%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \color{white}
    \draw (0,0) +(3ex,0) node[anchor=west]{Chapter \thechapter{} \filright#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chaptertitle}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Some remarks:

1. `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` is not needed since no `@` character is involved.
2. I've put `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` outside the definition.
3. I've removed some spurious spaces in the definition adding `%` at the end of some lines

---

### EDIT

To achieve the same result for unnumbered chapters as `\tableofcontents` you have to declare a separate `\titleformat`:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
{\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{}
{\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\hoffset-1in}
{%
    \tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[fill=cyan]%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \color{white}
    \draw (0,0) +(3ex,0) node[anchor=west]{#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage[uppercase, sf, explicit, raggedright]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{}
{\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\hoffset-1in}
{%
    \tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[fill=cyan]%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \color{white}
    \draw (0,0) +(3ex,0) node[anchor=west]{Chapter \thechapter{} \filright#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
{\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{}
{\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-\hoffset-1in}
{%
    \tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[fill=cyan]%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
    \color{white}
    \draw (0,0) +(3ex,0) node[anchor=west]{#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chaptertitle}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Output (ToC)

[image]

Comment: Huh. I missed the forest for the trees there. How would I put it right at the edge of the page then? `{-\oddsidemargin-\hoffset-1in}` does not seem to work...

Comment: That does the job just perfect.

Comment: @Peter-BenediktvonNiebelschtz Happy to help :-)

Comment: Addition to the problem: I added `\tableofcontents` and now the Box of every Chapter moves a bit to the right again. The Title of the TOC itself comes out as if I hadn't tried to move it at all...

Comment: Got the Chaptertitles back in Line by removing whitespace in the tikzpicture. Still, the Title of TOC behaves different than all the other Chapters. Is there a different switch for the TOC-Title?

Comment: @P-B See the edit.